# Should a skimming victim automatically contact the police as well as his financial institution?

Tags: atm

I'm concerned about the appropriateness of my response to the following incident:

My debit card was skimmed.  The skimming was discovered when we saw nine debit card transactions that we hadn't completed.  The card was skimmed somewhere in Pennsylvania and used at a Cub Food store in Minnesota.  I called the bank to cancel our card and visited the bank to report the incident and fill out paperwork.

I had also called the store where my card information was used and spoke with their Customer Service Manager.  She used the transaction information I gave her to determine that the person who used my card was male and had completed all nine transactions in a short period of time at a "Quick Checkout" line.  He would purchase a $1 or 2$ item and get $50 Cash Back with each transaction.  The CSM at Cub Foods told me to contact my bank and report the incident to the police.

The Bank Manager told me not to call the police--their investigators would do that.  Although the money has been credited to my account, I am still wondering if I should have contacted the police in spite of what the Bank Manager told me.  I was told by one person at the bank that they would likely just "eat the loss" and not take further action.

Although I have been made whole in this situation, in the interest of preventing the perpetrator from committing further acts of theft, should a victim of skimming assure that the police are involved by contacting them directly?

Comment: Your question does not deal with Information Security but with legal / procedural practices (bank and police). We will not be able to help you - you may try at SE.Law but I doubt this will be on topic either.